# Apache shut down unexpectly xampp

Tags: php, apache

I downloaded php 7.4 to replace with php7.3.
I move php 7.4 to xampp folder and rename old php folder with different name.
after that restart apache.

```
[Fri Feb 11 12:46:33.751685 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7948:tid 580] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 4032
[Fri Feb 11 12:46:34.268497 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 4032:tid 580] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Feb 11 12:46:34.346148 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 4032:tid 580] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Feb 11 12:46:34.377653 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4032:tid 580] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Fri Feb 11 13:12:35.902924 2022] [php7:error] [pid 4032:tid 1844] [client ::1:53129] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\\xampp\\phpMyAdmin\\libraries\\classes\\Dbal\\DbiMysqli.php on line 246
[Fri Feb 11 15:34:38.829295 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 11328:tid 568] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Feb 11 15:34:39.230678 2022] [core:warn] [pid 11328:tid 568] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
[Fri Feb 11 15:34:39.236676 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 11328:tid 568] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Feb 11 15:34:39.306825 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11328:tid 568] AH00455: Apache/2.4.51 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1l PHP/7.3.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Feb 11 15:34:39.307821 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11328:tid 568] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Oct  8 2021 10:03:59
[Fri Feb 11 15:34:39.307821 2022] [core:notice] [pid 11328:tid 568] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Fri Feb 11 15:34:39.312818 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 11328:tid 568] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 8416
[Fri Feb 11 15:34:39.927399 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 8416:tid 660] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Feb 11 15:34:40.270899 2022] [ssl:warn] [pid 8416:tid 660] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Feb 11 15:34:40.302876 2022] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 8416:tid 660] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Apache cannot run.
what wrong ?
How can fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try help you.

Go in xampp control panel and go in apache->config-> apache(httpd-xampp.conf)
You need change path of "LoadFile" and "LoadModule" to new version of php and new directory. This is an example

> LoadFile"D:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
>
> LoadFile"D:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
>
> LoadModule php7_module"D:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

I hope I was helpful.
Best regards,